# Преобразование даты в unix time

Tags: php

Сообствено вопрос таков, имеем задачу, время формата 10.04.2016 конвертировать в юникс время типа - time()
Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '10.04.2016';
$b = new Datetime($a);
$c = var_dump($b);
$d = $b->format('c');
var_dump($d);
```

Comment: вы мне дали масив какой то, мне нужно получить юникс дату.

Comment: $d = $b->format('U');
    var_dump($d);
UNIX timestamp?

Comment: и зачем такие извращения если можно просто - echo strtotime ( '10.04.2016' );